# Is it possible to connect a Android phone display to a TV or PC Monitor?

Tags: screen, external-display

Is it possible to make the display on a Android phone to a TV or a PC Monitor?

What are the methods that I can connect the Android phone to a TV (e.g. plasma TV) or a PC Monitor and then modify some configuration in the phone so that the display will be shown in the TV or the PC Monitor screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can connect an android phone to a TV or a computer monitor. At least if you have a new enough TV or monitor, and not a ten year old TV like I do. :-)
My android phone came with a HDMI cable to use when connecting phone to TV. I have connected it many times to my computer however, using a mini USB cable. But I would be able to use the HDMI as well, depending on what I want to do.

I am for sure no expert, but I have a Sony Ericsson experia arc S and I have used it for over a year. I hope that this answer is good enough to offer some help.

For newer phone, you may wish to use the following:

**Micro USB to HDMI® MHL Adapter**
[image]

Reference link: http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=8675&seq=1&format=2

Video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=P5tJl_a_wcc

In the reference link, it include information such as Compatible Mobile Devices (which you can retrieve from this link - http://www.mhlconsortium.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=5055)

Comment: May I have a illustration of the mini USB cable that you are referring to? Also, I notice that most Computer Monitor have a VGA port, a HDMI port and a DVI port. So, I am a bit puzzle how you can use a mini USB cable to connect to a computer monitor. And also, does the user do not need to modify any settings on the phone and the display on the phone will be projected / shown on the TV or a computer monitor with just a simple step by connecting the cable itself? (I am just surprise that the answer is so simple. Too shock to be true.)

Comment: On many recent phones/tablets, the "micro USB" port is actually a hybrid USB-[MHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-definition_Link) port.  An appropriate adapter ([like this monoprice unit](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=8675&seq=1&format=2)) will connect this port to a standard HDMI port.

Comment: @Compro01 That a good link. I updated the answer to include that useful information.

Comment: @Compro01 By the way, I notice that the adapter that you refer does not cover all the recent phones (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S III Mini), so are there other ways for such phones that is not compatible?

Comment: It is worth noting that not all devices support MHL. I remember that Samsung Galaxy Nexus supports, but the Nexus 7 tablet doesn't.

Comment: @jack - For unknown reasons, Samsung opted not to include MHL support in the GS3 mini.  About the only way I can think of to move video to screen on non-MHL devices would be DLNA (which would require appropriate hardware on the TV side) or similar.

Comment: @user26287 What things would I need to connect my VGA-cabled CRT TV ?

Comment: As @DenilsonSáMaia said, MHL support is mandatory for this to work. No MHL? No party! Don't buy any cable/adapter if you don't have MHL support on either your USB port or dedicated mini-HDMI port.

Answer (score 1):

Chromecast recently added the ability to cast your phone screen to the TV.  Most nexus devices have this support via the OS, and others will require an update to the Chromecast app.  This feature is working well with good resolution and a small amount of latency, so if you have one give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think micro-usb/HDMI adapter connection is a better option if your phone supports it and you have the required hardware, another option for viewing your screen on the computer is is to use USB debugging mode capabilities, which does not require special hardware beyond your USB cable.

Essentially, you enable USB debugging mode on the phone. You install the Android SDK on your computer. You probably will also have to install USB drivers for your phone model as well that are not the default drivers that do USB folder storage only. And then you download an application called **Android Screencast** to your PC and run it. It's slightly laggy, so it isn't ideal for, say, watching a video off your phone, but if your screen dies or something, it can be a lifesaver. A detailed tutorial on how to get Android screencast up and running is here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42491/how-to-remote-view-and-control-your-android-phone/

Answer (score 0):

This is what developers use to show applications to an audience:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/project-your-android-phones-screen-onto-a-larger-display/

1. A hardware phone screen projector like Paraben's Project-A-Phone ICD-5200. Expensive.
2. Eclipse and the Android SDK, and then run your application in the Android emulator. Slow.
3. A free application called Droid@Screen.

Comment: Please at least summarize the contents of the link you posted in case it gets moved or deleted. If the link dies the answer has no value whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as far as I know you can only connect it to your smart tv or blueray player to play media storage; like videos, music, photos, etc.
I don't think they have live playback for android, but they do for PSP Go.

Comment: Is this a guess, or have you tried it? HDMI has a "mirror" mode, where the device's screen is "mirrored" to the display connected via HDMI -- i.e. on the TV you then see exactly the same content as on your screen (only problem: not all Android phones have a HDMI (or MHL) port available for this). Furthermore, using some uPnP server app on Android (e.g. [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)) you can control playback remotely -- but that wasn't even asked by the OP :)

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it is I connect my phone to my tv by using a micro usb to yellow video input and use my Curtis 5.1 dolby surround sound with a female red and white to male audio (headset connecter).

Comment: Could you mention what kind of phone this works on, and what kind of video adaptor you're using? I wouldn't expect most phones to support this.