# Can I connect LG G2 to TV via USB?

Tags: usb, lg-g2, smart-tv

I have LG G2 and a TV which has a USB port. The TV can recognise when I put a flash drive into its USB port and it plays videos like a computer, but I would like to ask:

1. Can I use my phone also as a flash disk? Is it safe? Could it create problems for my phone?
2. When I watch a video on my phone on the internet via a wireless connection, can I watch the video at the same time on the TV as well?

All I have is this cable which I use for connecting my phone to the computer.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to connect a Android phone display to a TV or PC Monitor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37043/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-android-phone-display-to-a-tv-or-pc-monitor)

Comment: Q.1 is possible if your phone is rooted. For Q.2, Only if you have HDMI support in your TV, you can buy a suitable chromecast device and do it. AFAIK, you can't mirror Android Device to TV via USB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, DriveDroid is excellent at doing this. Boot the app, create a new image however big you want, format it (DriveDroid will by default make it a FAT filesystem, but if you wanted to you could use the DiskPart utility of windows to format it to NTFS.) The default will work fine though. Then when you tab the USB button and mount as a Writable USB, it will act like a flash drive to whatever you plug it into.
2. Depending on your type of TV and the USB interface it uses this may be possible. Using an app like TVP may be able to stream torrent videos over USB to the TV, but I'm unsure. I would suggest using DLNA to do this with apps such as LocalCast or AllCast. It can stream the video to your TV if it is a smart TV, or if it is connected to an XBox, playstation, or any DLNA compatible device (roku, chromecast). Depending on your TV model you may be able to stream directly over USB, but I have never tried to do this as my TV is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since LG is not MHL compatible, you need to order a SlimPort adapter for LG if your TV is HDMI.

Samsung and I believe I know Samsung is run off of MHL and they make an MHL-to-HDMI Micro USB.

Comment: Are you sure about that, bobby? You're pretty generic on LG with your answer. I've used my LG with an MHL cable fine (not a G2, though, but an Optimus 4X HD).